# Calculate the Cummulative Distribution of a weighted average within a group

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that looks like the following

```
VENDOR  AREA   YEAR  PERCENT_OF_WORK  RATE
A       DEN    2020  30               100
B       DEN    2020  70               200
...
N       2020  0                500
```

I would like to calculate some statistics about the rates so I've done this so far:

```
SELECT 
  AREA,
  YEAR,
  COUNT(DISTINCT VENDOR) AS "VENDOR_COUNT",
  MIN(RATE) AS "MIN",
  ROUND(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.1) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RATE ASC),2) AS "P90"
  ROUND(AVG(RATE),2) AS "P50",
  ROUND(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RATE ASC),2) AS "P10",
  MAX(RATE) AS "MAX",
  ROUND(STDDEV(RATE),2) AS "STDDEV"
  SUM(RATE*PERCENT_OF_WORK/100) AS "WEIGHTED_RATE"
FROM BIDS
GROUP BY AREA, YEAR
```

The next thing I'd like to add the the Cumulative Distribution of the weighted rate per group. i.e. what Pvalue does the weighted rate have compared to all the bids.

This is what I've tried by it doesn't work:

```
CUME_DIST(SUM(RATE*PERCENT_OF_WORK/100)) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY RATE ASC ) AS "Pvalue"
```

Thank you for the help!

Sample Data

```
WITH DATA AS (
  SELECT 'DEN' AS "AREA", 2020 AS "YEAR", 'A' AS "VENDOR", 30 as "PERCENT_OF_WORK", 400 AS "RATE" FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'DEN' AS "AREA", 2020 AS "YEAR", 'B' AS "VENDOR", 10 as "PERCENT_OF_WORK", 700 AS "RATE" FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'DEN' AS "AREA", 2020 AS "YEAR", 'C' AS "VENDOR", 0 as "PERCENT_OF_WORK", 1000 AS "RATE" FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'DEN' AS "AREA", 2020 AS "YEAR", 'D' AS "VENDOR", 20 as "PERCENT_OF_WORK", 600 AS "RATE" FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'DEN' AS "AREA", 2020 AS "YEAR", 'E' AS "VENDOR", 40 as "PERCENT_OF_WORK", 250 AS "RATE" FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'HOU' AS "AREA", 2021 AS "YEAR", 'A' AS "VENDOR", 30 as "PERCENT_OF_WORK", 400 AS "RATE" FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'HOU' AS "AREA", 2021 AS "YEAR", 'B' AS "VENDOR", 10 as "PERCENT_OF_WORK", 700 AS "RATE" FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'HOU' AS "AREA", 2021 AS "YEAR", 'C' AS "VENDOR", 0 as "PERCENT_OF_WORK", 1000 AS "RATE" FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'HOU' AS "AREA", 2021 AS "YEAR", 'D' AS "VENDOR", 20 as "PERCENT_OF_WORK", 600 AS "RATE" FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'HOU' AS "AREA", 2021 AS "YEAR", 'E' AS "VENDOR", 40 as "PERCENT_OF_WORK", 250 AS "RATE" FROM DUAL
)
SELECT 
  AREA,
  YEAR,
  COUNT( DISTINCT VENDOR) AS "BIDS",
  MIN(RATE) AS "MIN",
  ROUND(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.1) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RATE ASC),2) AS "P90",
  ROUND(AVG(RATE),2) AS "P50",
  ROUND(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RATE ASC),2) AS "P10",
  MAX(RATE) AS "MAX",
  ROUND(STDDEV(RATE),2) AS "STDDEV",
  CUME_DIST(SUM(RATE*PERCENT_OF_WORK/100)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RATE)  AS "PValue",
  SUM(RATE*PERCENT_OF_WORK/100) AS "WEIGHTED_RATE"
FROM DATA
GROUP BY AREA, YEAR
```

Expected Answer
[image: Table Result]

PValue of 0.26 was calculated using the NORM.DIST function in excel with the sample mean and standard deviation.

Error Message

> ORA-30496: Argument should be a constant.
> 30496. 00000 -  "Argument should be a constant."
> *Cause:
> *Action:
> Error at Line: 49 Column: 17

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data in text format and describe what "doesn't work" mean

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I have made the edits @anstentx

Comment: I've added some sample data @GordonLinoff

Comment: Apparently, `cume_dist` only accepts constant arguments when used as an aggregate function. Is the 0.266055 `Pvalue` a correct value for the sample data? I can't seem to get how you computed it.

Comment: I used the norm_dist function in excel with the mean and the standard deviation. I’m not sure if that was the correct approach since the rates aren’t a normal distribution. Sorry I should have mentioned that @Junjie